# Make the JTable cell ready to be overwritten

Tags: swing, jtable

I have a button which inserts a single column row into a JTable with the text: 
"New notes: ". I want this text ready to be overwritten as soon as the user starts typing on this cell (rightafter the button-press). How to make the JTable's cell ready to be overwritten? How can this be done?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use a custom `TableCellEditor`, when `getTableCellEditorComponent` is called, if the `value` is `null`, you would seed the editor with your prompt and call the `selectAll` method (assuming you are using some kind of `JTextComponent` for the editor).

This may require you to call `selectAll` within a `SwingUtilities.invokeLater` call.

Alternatively, you could have a look at this [prompt](http://code.google.com/p/xswingx/) API